# How to write a GPT prompt programmatically?

Tags: prompt, openai-api, f-string, chatgpt-api

I have a template prompt similar to this one:

````
prompt = f"""
Write a poem about the topic delimited by triple backticks if it starts with a consonant, 
otherwise say 
"foo". 
Topic: ```{topic}```
"""
````

and a list of topics:

```
topics = ['cuddly pandas', 'ugly bears', 'sketchy Elons']
```

I would like to query the OpenAI API with the same base prompt, for each topic in `topics`. How can I do that? This works, but it seems a bit inelegant to have to redefine the f-string at each iteration of the for loop:

````
for topic in topics:
    prompt = f"""
    Write a poem about the topic delimited by triple backticks if the first word of the topic  starts with a 
    consonant, 
    otherwise say 
    "foo". 
    Topic: ```{topic}```
     """
    print(prompt)
````

Comment: Did you try ask chatgpt?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can try something like this:

````
topic_str = """
Write a poem about the topic delimited by triple backticks if the first word of the topic  starts with a 
consonant, 
otherwise say 
"foo". 
Topic:```"""

for topic in topics:
    prompt = topic_str+f"{topic}"+"```"
    print(prompt)
````